Cloudflare Worker: SVG with embedded image not displaying when used in <img> tag
Problem Description
I'm generating an SVG using a Cloudflare Worker that includes an external logo image. The logo displays correctly when I open the SVG link directly in the browser, but fails to load when the SVG is referenced in an <img> tag.
Minimal Reproducible Example
function generateLogoElement(logoUrl, width, theme) {
  if (!logoUrl) return '';

  // Using jsdelivr as image source
  return `
    <image x="${width - 85}" y="10" width="65" height="34" 
           href="${logoUrl}" 
           preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" 
           crossorigin="anonymous" 
           referrerpolicy="no-referrer"/>
  `;
}

Specific Environment Details

Platform: Cloudflare Worker
Image Source: jsdelivr CDN / raw.githubusercontent.com
Browsers Tested: Chrome, Edge (Latest Versions)

Observed Behavior

✅ Direct browser link: Logo displays correctly
❌ <img> tag: Logo fails to load
✅ <object> tag: Logo displays correctly

Attempted Solutions

Added cross-origin and security headers:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: cross-origin
Content-Security-Policy


Verified image sources:

Multiple CDN providers
Checked image URLs directly



Specific Questions

Why does the logo not load when used in an <img> tag?
What CORS or security configurations might be preventing the image load?

Debugging Attempted

Checked network logs
No visible errors in browser console
No request blocks detected

Additional Context:

SVG is generated dynamically
Logo is an external webp image
Works perfectly with <object> tag

Can anyone provide insights into why the logo image is not displaying in the <img> tag?

Because loading of external resources gets blocked in this instance. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/SVG_as_an_Image#restrictions
